# Invalid absolute dimension: inf. The dimension must be a finite value

Tags: swift, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Hi I tried to use compositional layout, while using stage manager rare the app getting crashed. Please refer below error message

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid absolute
> dimension: inf. The dimension must be a finite value.'

code

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(cellWidth),heightDimension: .absolute(cellHeight))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(cellHeight))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            group.interItemSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutSpacing.fixed(cellSpacing)
            
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10,leading: inset, bottom: 0,trailing:inset)
            section.interGroupSpacing = lineSpacing
```

Comment: On which line is your code crashing? What are the values of your variables (`cellWidth` ... `cellHeight` ... `cellSpacing` ...etc)?

Comment: cell width and height are depends on container size( layoutEnvironment.container.contentSize) .  The app crashes at the first line

Comment: I meant... when you debug this, what are the values you are getting for `cellWidth` and `cellHeight`? Are they what you *expect* to get?

Answer (score -1):

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(cellWidth),heightDimension: .absolute(cellHeight))
```

In case this line produces exception due to infinite parameter, that may happen due to division by zero when calculating `cellWidth` or `cellHeight`. I can assume you're diving total width of collection component by count of elements, or similar. Avoid division by zero issues by adding security checks for this edge case.